# Sum multiple workbooks using VBA without choosing manually

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple workbooks with one sheet each ("Blank").  I then have another workbook that has multiple worksheets, one of which is a master input sheet ("Inputs") and another is the location I'm trying to sum the workbooks to ("Totals").  I have the following code written, it does work to total the workbooks, but what I would like to do is not have the manual file selection.  Please help.

```
    Sub Sum()

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Totals").Range("D12:H52").ClearContents
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Totals").Range("D65:H80").ClearContents

    Dim File_Name As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim fp As String

    'This is the section that is not working, Cell M3 defines the folder location and column Q is the filenames.xlsx
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Name As String 
    LastRow = MyWorksheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
    Set fp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inputs").Range("M3")
    Set Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inputs").Range("Q7:" & LastRow)

    File_Name = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files, *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)

    If Not IsArray(File_Name) Then Exit Sub
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For i = LBound(File_Name) To UBound(File_Name)
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(File_Name(i))
        wb.Sheets("Blank").Range("K12:O52").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Totals").Range("D12:H52").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
        wb.Sheets("Blank").Range("K65:O80").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Totals").Range("D65:H80").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next i

    MsgBox "Done"

   With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to process all files in a folder?

Comment: Yes, it would be all files in a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Sum()

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Totals").Range("D12:H52").ClearContents
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Totals").Range("D65:H80").ClearContents

    Dim myPath As String: myPath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inputs").Range("M3")
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject 'you will require Microsoft Scripting Runtime library for this
    Dim myFolder As Folder: Set myFolder = fso.GetFolder(myPath)
    Dim myFile As File

    For Each myFile In myFolder.Files
        If Not myFile.Name Like "*.xls*" Then GoTo SkipFile
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myFile.Path, False, True)
        wb.Sheets("Blank").Range("K12:O52").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Totals").Range("D12:H52").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlAdd, True
        wb.Sheets("Blank").Range("K65:O80").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Totals").Range("D65:H80").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlAdd, True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        wb.Close False
SkipFile:
    Next myFile

    MsgBox "Done"

    With Application
         .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
         .DisplayAlerts = True
         .ScreenUpdating = True
     End With

End Sub
```

Will take all the files from the folder defined in `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inputs").Range("M3")`

Comment: Thanks you for the help.  The only change I had to make was to define wb.

Comment: Yeah! Sorry for that @TreeDT was cleaning the code from variables and deleted that one too.

Comment: A great reminder that there is more than one argument (parameter) in [Workbooks.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) and [Range.PasteSpecial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial).